# Finding the exponent (without using POW or built in functions) of a number using a procedure and/or Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a way to find the exponent of a number (in this case the base is 4 and the exponent 2 so the answer should be 16) using a procedure without using the POW Function or any built in functions to find the exponent. Eventually I would like to take input numbers from the user.

```
    set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Exponent(base number, exponent number) as
answer number;
BEGIN
   base := 4;
   exponent := 2;

   LOOP
   IF exponent > 1 THEN
        answer := base * base;
   END IF;
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line('Answer is: ' || answer);
END;
/
```

Error(7,25): PLS-00103: "expression 'BASE' cannot be used as an assignment target" and "expression 'EXPONENT' cannot be used as an assignment target"

Any ideas on how to solve the error and/or better ways of getting the exponent without using built-in functions like POW?

Comment: remove the `declare`

Comment: thank you. After I removed it I seemed to be getting the error: "Error(7,25): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current delete exists prior The symbol "<an identifier> was inserted before "PROCEDURE" to continue. " Should I post this as a different question?

Comment: We can help you make the code bug-free, but it doesn't seem like that will help you much. What do you mean by "trying to find the exponent" - you are giving it as an input, so why do you need to "find" it? Do you mean you are trying to compute the **power**, not the exponent? Then, your code just multiplies the base by itself; if the exponent is 3 or more, that's the wrong computation. It seems you moved on to coding before having a clear idea of the math needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah the math is what I'm also having trouble finding out how to be sure to accomplish. I was thinking that I could just use a LOOP to make sure it multiplies the base by itself for the right number of times.

Comment: If I run the code from your question, I get: "*expression 'BASE' cannot be used as an assignment target*" and "*expression 'EXPONENT' cannot be used as an assignment target*" (which makes sense, you can't assign values to parameter) - so you are apparently running something different then you showed us.

Comment: OK, you are having trouble with the math. Can you describe the problem in words? It seems you want to compute powers, but without using the built-in `power()` function, right? Like, the user inputs base = 17 and exponent = 5, and you must return 17 to the power 5 (17 * 17 * 17 * 17 * 17)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your procedure `base` and `exponent` are input parameters and can't be changed. You've got a couple of options:

1) copy the parameters to variables internal to the procedure and manipulate those internal values, or
2) change the parameters to be input/output parameters so you can change them.

Examples:

1)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Exponent(pin_base number, pin_exponent number) as
  base number := pin_base;
  exponent number := pin_exponent;
answer number;
BEGIN
   base := 4;
   exponent := 2;

   LOOP
   IF exponent > 1 THEN
        answer := base * base;
   END IF;
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line('Answer is: ' || answer);
END;
```

2)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Exponent(base IN OUT number,
                                     exponent IN OUT number) as
answer number;
BEGIN
   base := 4;
   exponent := 2;

   LOOP
   IF exponent > 1 THEN
        answer := base * base;
   END IF;
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line('Answer is: ' || answer);
END;
```

Comment: Is this meant to help just with syntax errors? Clearly "base * base" will not compute powers with exponent greater than 2. And it is quite pointless to take base and exponent from the user, only to change them to fixed values in the procedure (Option 2).

Comment: Yes, it's just there to help with syntax. The purpose of the homework (which is what I strongly suspect this is) is to learn how to do exponentiation without resorting to library functions, and far be it from me to interfere with someone's education. As it turns out, I *do* happen to have such a routine around but, oh darn, it's in Clojure (Lisp variant) - and it'd be really tough to translate it to PL/SQL. I doubt it could be done... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is that whatever Oracle provides as inbuilt functionality that serves the purpose in a best possible. (Almost all the times better then customized codes) Try to use EXP function. I have tried to make customized code per my understanding. Hope this helps.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION EXP_DUMMY(
      BASE_IN IN NUMBER,
      EXPO_IN IN NUMBER)
    RETURN PLS_INTEGER
  AS
    lv PLS_INTEGER:=1;
  BEGIN
    FOR I IN
    (SELECT base_in COL1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY level < expo_in+1
    )
    LOOP
      lv:=lv*i.col1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN
    CASE
    WHEN EXPO_IN = 0 THEN
      1
    ELSE
      lv
    END;
  END;

SELECT EXP_DUMMY(2,4) FROM DUAL;
```